# Wildfly 15.0.1 JAX-RS @BeanParam NPE for getter methods

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I am testing JAX-RS annoration @BeanParam in Wildfly 15.0.1, but am getting NPE when trying to access field values via getter methods.

If I use @FormParam instead, everything works fine. In Eclipse debugger, if I access the field directly (not via getter method) the value is there. However, if I try to access the field value via its getter method, it returns null and hence the NPE. Below are screenshots from Eclipse debugger showing the field has value, but the getter method is returning null.

[image]

[image]

The code snippets of what I am trying to do:

```
@RequestScoped  
public class TestFilter {  
    @FormParam("date_fr")  
    private String dateFr;  
    ...  
}  

@ApplicationScoped  
@Path("/test")  
public class TestRes {  
    @POST  
    @Path("/search")  
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)  
    public Response search(@BeanParam TestFilter filter) throws IOException {  
        if (filter.getDateFr().length() > 0) { // NPE here: filter.getDateFr() is null  

        }  
    }  
}
```

Anyone know what's going on with the @BeanParam here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `@RequestScoped`?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha No particular reason. I was just testing JAX-RS capabilities. But you are right, without `@RequestScoped` it works. I also tested with OpenLiberty and it had no problems with `@RequestScoped`. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not. I hope someone familiar with the relevant specs can say more.

Comment: Different implementations will have different behaviors to things that are not mentioned in the specification, which this use case isn’t. For this particular case, there is no reason why a BeanParam should have a scope annotation.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Something doesn't feel quite right. Without an explicit scope annotation, aren't the beans by default `@Dependent` scoped? If that's true, then why should a different scope make the `@BeanParam` behave differently in this case?

Comment: The beans are tied to the specific request. There is no reason it should be in any other scope. It is meant specifically to combine `@XxxParam`s into one bean for easy access. CDI is not involved. The JAX-RS implementation handles the creation of this bean and you should leave it to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the `@RequestScoped` annotation. Without that, it works as expected.

Someone has reported a Jira bug against this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-11680